# Импорт плагина для jQuery в Symfony

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, webpack, symfony

Через yarn добавил плагин для jQuery https://github.com/Script47/Toast
В своем js файле импортирую его и пытаюсь вызвать:

```
const $ = require('jquery');
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
global.bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
...
require('bs4-toast');
...
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.toast({
        title: 'Toast',
        subtitle: '11 mins ago',
        content: 'Hello, world! This is a toast message.',
        type: 'info',
        delay: 5000
    });
});
```

При вызове $.toast в консоль вываливается ошибка:

```
jquery.js:3841 jQuery.Deferred exception: $.toast is not a function TypeError: $.toast is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://192.168.117.39:8000/build/app.3b791728.js:1687:5)
    at mightThrow (https://192.168.117.39:8000/build/app.3b791728.js:39968:29)
    at process (https://192.168.117.39:8000/build/app.3b791728.js:40036:12) undefined
app.js:1105 Uncaught TypeError: $.toast is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:1105)
    at mightThrow (jquery.js:3557)
    at process (jquery.js:3625)
```

Что я делаю не так? Как правильно вызвать нужный метод плагина?

Comment: А вы не через encore подключаете библиотеки на фронт ? 

https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/legacy-applications.html

Comment: Через него и подключаю, все как по указанной ссылке

Comment: Я честно говоря уже подзабыл как и что, но я помню что именно c jquery плагинами были сложности, посмотрите вот тут -  https://github.com/Kolbasyatin/IFS/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Возможно вам нужно будет добавить что то типа 

`.autoProvideVariables({
        "window.jQuery": "jquery",
        "$.jPlayer": "jplayer",
        "Routing": "router"
    })`

но там ниже есть еще resolver.alias и я честно говоря не очень помню как это работает. Но помню что в итоге я плагины заставил работать.

Comment: `В своем js файле импортирую его` как раз в примере импорта то и не видно. Сам js плагина в шаблоне добавлен? Или где он импортируется?